# javascript onload event for textarea(s) character countdown

Tags: php, javascript

I'm pulling data from a database and displaying it in a textarea(s). I have a characters count down javascript. the textarea(s) are being repeated for each entry from the database/table.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
<!-- Begin
    function textCounter(field,cntfield,maxlimit) {
        if (field.value.length > maxlimit) // if too long...trim it!
            field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
// otherwise, update 'characters left' counter
        else
            cntfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
}
//  End -->
</script>
```

Here is the php:

```
echo "<b>$ID : $adname</b><br /><a href=\"?action=deletead&IDnum=$ID\">Delete Ad</a><br /><br />\n";
    echo "Preview :<br /><div class=\"adcode\">$adcode</div><br /> \n";
    echo "<br />\n";
    echo "<form action=\"displayads.php\" name=\"addAD$ID\" method=\"post\">\n";
    echo "AD code (can be any type of script) text link, javascript or banner :<br />\n";
    echo "Code :<br /><textarea name=\"adcode$ID\" wrap=\"physical\" cols=\"60\" rows=\"5\" onKeyDown=\"textCounter(document.addAD$ID.adcode$ID,document.addAD$ID.remLen$ID,5000)\" onKeyUp=\"textCounter(document.addAD$ID.adcode$ID,document.addAD$ID.remLen$ID,5000)\">$adcode</textarea>";
    echo "<br /><input readonly type=\"text\" name=\"remLen$ID\" size=\"3\" maxlength=\"3\" value=\"5000\">Characters Left \n";
    echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"editad$ID\" value=\"Edit AD Code\"></form>\n";
    echo "<br /><hr />";
```

The question is how can I do an onload page load event to make all the textarea(s) with the unique name textarea name=\"adcode$ID\" reflect the correct character count onload. instead now it reflects the right amount only when you change the information in the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty way to do it would be to loop through the textareas and fire off the function bound to the `onkeyup` event...

```
(function () {
    var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'),
        i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < textareas.length; i += 1) {
        textareas[i].onkeyup();
    }
}());​
```

**UPDATE:**

Yes, this should be run on load, or at least after the textareas have rendered.

```
function addHandler(obj, evType, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evType, fn, false);
        return true;
    } else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        var r = obj.attachEvent("on" + evType, fn);
        return r;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
addHandler(window, 'load', function () {
    var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'),
        i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < textareas.length; i += 1) {
        //fire off the "onkeyup" handler.
        textareas[i].onkeyup();
    }
});
```

or:

```
<!-- this script block should be inserted after all of the textareas. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'),
            i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < textareas.length; i += 1) {
            //fire off the "onkeyup" handler.
            textareas[i].onkeyup();
        }
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: can this be an onload event. i couldn't get it to work for onkeyup

Comment: thanks for the help. the code helps me see how to do a function onload  to all 'textarea' or other form field types with needed math.
thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Or you could handle it in php:

```
$adcode = substr($adcode,0,5000);

echo '<input readonly type="text" name="remLen' . $ID . '" ' .
         'size="3" maxlength="3" value="' . (5000 - strlen($adcode)) . '">' . 
         'Characters Left' . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: i don't see how this works. I tried to use it and edit it into working no luck, any more details. sorry still newish to php

Comment: The first line just handles the same thing that your JS does for cutting down the length to 5000 chars, the second should be used to replace your "Characters left" input from the code you have above. It calculates the length of the text that will be in the textarea & displays the number of chars the user has left before reaching 5000. You'll still need your JS in place to handle the dynamic changes that the use will make, but with the above you wont need to worry about firing that JS on the page load -- unless your JS does anything more fancy than just controlling the "characters left" value?